# MongoDB - Windows 10 service autostart fails after enabling Authorization and BindIP change

Tags: mongodb, windows-10

I am running mongoDB on windows 10 machine. It is setup to autostart on system startup. All worked as expeced but then i changed the configuration file in two ways.

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\data
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\log\mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 10.255.2.155  //Changed Here -My local network IP

#processManagement:

security://Changed HERE
  authorization: "enabled" //Changed HERE

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

//Changed HERE comments are here just for you to see. They are not in the config.

Logs of the failed start

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-09T05:55:03.534+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-09T05:55:03.564+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-09T05:55:03.577+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-09T05:55:07.032+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-09T05:55:07.073+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-09T05:55:07.073+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-09T05:55:07.073+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-09T05:55:07.073+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-09T05:55:07.073+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23316,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Trying to start Windows service","attr":{"serviceName":"MongoDB"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-09T05:55:07.077+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":3852,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/6.0/data","architecture":"64-bit","host":"TOPCORE_Process_1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-09T05:55:07.077+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-09T05:55:07.077+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.2","gitVersion":"94fb7dfc8b974f1f5343e7ea394d0d9deedba50e","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-09T05:55:07.078+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 17763)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-09T05:55:07.078+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\6.0\\bin\\mongod.cfg","net":{"bindIp":"10.255.2.155","port":27017},"security":{"authorization":"enabled"},"service":true,"storage":{"dbPath":"C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\6.0\\data","journal":{"enabled":true}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\6.0\\log\\mongod.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-09T05:55:07.084+02:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlistend","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"The requested address is not valid in its context."}}}
```

When i open windows services and manually start the service. It works fine.
How is it possible that manual start works but automatic fails ?

I checked the logs for the sucesfully manual start and they are identical up the the crash line.
Thanx for any suggestions.

I checked the logs for the sucesfully manual start and they are identical up the the crash line.
Thanx for any suggestions.

Comment: net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0 Solves the problem with startup but i still dont know why binding to localnetwork IP fails on startup

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use

```
net:
  bindIpAll: true
```

or

```
net:
  bindIp: localhost
```

Depending on your requirements. Use `bindIp: localhost` if you like to permit connections only from the local machine. Use `bindIpAll: true` if you like to permit connections also from remote machines.

In my opinion `bindIp: 10.255.2.155` makes only sense on a computer with multiple network interfaces. However, since MongoDB does not support multiple interfaces (see for example [Oracle Exadata Network Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/en/engineered-systems/exadata-cloud-at-customer/eccid/exacc_netinterfaces.html)) it does not make much sense either.
Also depending on your network settings, this IP may change at any time.

Just a note, it is rather uncommon to put log files or data files or configuration files under `C:\Program Files` folder. I would propose a folder under `%APPDATA%`, `%LOCALAPPDATA%` or a dedicated folder, e.g. `C:\MongoDB`

Comment: Thanx for the answer. The machine is hooked on our local network with wireguard so i can connect to the mongo from my computer remotelly with the 10.255.2.xxx range.  I just used the folders from the instalation. I will change them according to your advice.